# Mean value theorem exercise

Tags: calculus

I tried to solve this exercise: 
Find the sum of the values satisfying the Mean Value Theorem of
$$f(x) = \frac13x^3 − 2x^2 + 3x + 4,$$
where $0 \le x \le 4$.

It's my first time solving these kind of exercises so I'd like to know if I did it right: 
I set $$f(4)-\frac{1}{4}f(0) = f'(c),$$ and found $f'(c) = 1/3,$ then set the $$x^2-4x+3 = 1/3$$ and found the values to be $x=(4\pm\sqrt{6})/2$.
All in all, the final result should be $4$, right? Could someone check my work?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say that the final result should be $4$, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct. Here's a solution that requires less calculation.

$f'(x)=x^2-4x+3$. Whatever the mean value $v$ that we equate this to, we get a quadratic equation $x^2-4x+3-v=0$. This can be factored into the form $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=0$, with $x_1$, $x_2$ the roots of the equation, and multiplying this out shows that $x_1+x_2=4$. Generally we'd have to check which of these solutions lie in the interval, but since the question asks for the sum of plural values, it could be taken to imply that both do, so the desired sum is $4$.